# Vertical scroll bar present or not in silverlight 3, c#?

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

How to know a ScrollViewer is currently scrolling or not in code behind (I mean *vertical scrollbar present or not*) in silverlight 3?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yea, I tried it by checking grid actual height against ScrollViewer height. It is working.. Any other method available? Without this checking..?

Comment: Check if ScrollableHeight is greater than 0?

Comment: yea it's scrollable height is greater than zero.